# Transact SQL - Information Schema

Tags: t-sql, db2

Is there a way to query an Information Schema from DB2 and dump the contents(tables - structure only),into another database? I'm looking for a way to create a shell model of a database schema from DB2 into a SQL Server database?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [db2look](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0002051.htm) to get the table structure (DDL) out of db2.

Once you've got it, however, I'm afraid you'll have to manually replace any db2-specific syntax (datatypes, storage parameters, etc.) with it's corresponding SQL Server syntax.

It doesn't look like Microsoft's [Migration Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/migration.aspx) works for db2 yet. :(